# angular js $scope variable binding with string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular doesn't recognize that when i put together model (string) and $scope to form $scope.model that it is indeed a defined scope variable. Is there anyway to not make model a string so $scope.model will actually refer to what I need it to refer to?

```
$scope.games = [];
    $scope.maxplayers = 0;
    $scope.minplayers = 0;

........

function setupWatcher(model){

  $scope.$watch(model,function(){

    console.log($scope.model);  // prints out undefined
    if(!$scope.model) return;




    $http.get('/api/games?'+ model + '=' + $scope.model)
      .success(function(data){
        $scope.games = data;

      })
      .error(function(data){
        console.log('Error' + data);
      });

  });
}

angular.forEach(['maxplayers',' minplayers'],setupWatcher);
```

Comment: Do you mean `$scope[model]`?

Comment: wow thank you so much.!Stupid syntax error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should do it like this

```
$scope[model]
```

You can access object properties either way

```
var propName = 'prop3',
  myObject = {
    prop1: "123",
    prop2: "456",
    prop3: "789"
};

myObject.prop1 // 123
myObject['prop2'] // 456
myObject[propName] // 789
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation:

```
$scope[model]
```